# Inversion of Matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

What is the inverse of the following (n x n)-matrix?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1 &0 &0 &... &0 &0 \\
-1 &2 &-1 &0 &... &0 &0 \\
0 &-1 &2 &-1 &... &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &-1 & 2 &... &0 &0 \\
... &... &... &... &... &... &... \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &... &2 &-1 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &... &-1 &2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using software to calculate the answer for $n$ up to $7$ suggests the following answer:
$$a_{i,j}=\cases{\frac{i(n+1-j)}{n+1}&if $i\le j$\cr \frac{j(n+1-i)}{n+1}&if $i\ge j$,\cr}$$
which is then easy to prove.